# How to put minus after each word?

Tags: php, regex

I am working on youtube video feed, and I want to transform each video title to seotitle.

I have a string like so: `'Kings Of Leon - Use Somebody'`

and I want it to be like this: `'Kings-Of-Leon-Use-Somebody'`.

I have try this code:

```
$seotitle=str_replace(' ','-',$video['title']['$t']);
```

but I get this '`Kings-Of-Leon-Use---Somebody'`

What is a good way to handle with extra spaces and minus?

Comment: Use a regular expression function, e.g. `preg_replace` - you can use the `+` device to specify a number of characters. Have a look at php.net/preg_replace for more info.

Comment: http://www.punctuationmatters.com/the-difference-between-a-dash-and-a-minus-sign/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$string = 'Kings Of Leon - Use Somebody';

// first replace anything but letters with space
$string = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', ' ', $string);

// then replace consecutive spaces with hypen
$string = preg_replace('/[ ]+/', '-', trim($string));
```

See inline comments for detail.

Answer (score 4):

A simple regex to do what you want is:

```
preg_replace('|[ -]+|', '-', $seotitle);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try This :**

```
//string assign to variable
$string = 'Kings Of Leon - Use Somebody';
//Removes whitespace or other predefined characters from the right side of a string
$string = ltrim($string);
// Removes whitespace or other predefined characters from both sides of a string
$string = rtrim($string);
// str replace methods
$string = str_replace(" ", "-", $string);
// RemoveSpecial Character
$string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/", "",$string);
// Remove Multiple -
$string = preg_replace('/-+/', '-',$string);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the same function to replace the ' - ' with ' ' like this:

```
$seotitle_temp=str_replace(' - ', ' ', 'Kings Of Leon - Use Somebody'); 
$seotitle_temp=str_replace(' ', '-', 'Kings Of Leon - Use Somebody');
```

Then you will go clear.

Comment: This will not have any _-_ in the title.

Comment: This will replace the line here 'Kings Of Leon - Use Somebody' and then replace spaces with '-' and he gets 'Kings-Of-Leon-Use-Somebody'. Try it.

Comment: I get the title with just spaces and no dashes.

Comment: The replace the spaces with dashes.

Comment: No, it replaces the one dash in the string with a space. `str_replace(' - ', ' ', 'Kings Of Leon - Use Somebody');` becomes _Kings Of Leon Use Somebody_

Comment: @putvande `str_replace(' - ', ' ', 'Kings Of Leon - Use Somebody');` `str_replace(' ', '-', 'Kings Of Leon - Use Somebody');`  Execute this.

Comment: If you make a variable out of it and put it trough the 2 str_replace it works. So put that as your answer.